# python: Two modules and classes with the same name under different packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

I have started to learn python and writing a practice app. The directory structure looks like

```
src
 |
 --ShutterDeck
    |
    --Helper
       |
       --User.py -> class User
    --Controller
       |
       --User.py -> class User
```

The `src` directory is in `PYTHONPATH`. In a different file, lets say `main.py`, I want to access both `User` classes. How can I do it.

I tried using the following but it fails:

```
import cherrypy
from ShutterDeck.Controller import User
from ShutterDeck.Helper import User

class Root:
  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return 'Hello World'

u1=User.User()
u2=User.User()
```

That's certainly ambiguous. The other (c++ way of doing it) way that I can think of is

```
import cherrypy
from ShutterDeck import Controller
from ShutterDeck import Helper

class Root:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return 'Hello World'

u1=Controller.User.User()
u2=Helper.User.User()
```

But when above script is run, it gives the following error

```
u1=Controller.User.User()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'User'
```

I'm not able to figure out why is it erroring out? The directories `ShutterDeck`, `Helper` and `Controller` have `__init__.py` in them.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You want to import the `User` modules in the package `__init__.py` files to make them available as attributes.

So in both `Helper/__init_.py` and `Controller/__init__.py` add:

```
from . import User
```

This makes the module an attribute of the package and you can now refer to it as such.

Alternatively, you'd have to import the modules themselves in full:

```
import ShutterDeck.Controller.User
import ShutterDeck.Helper.User

u1=ShutterDeck.Controller.User.User()
u2=ShutterDeck.Helper.User.User()
```

so refer to them with their full names.

Another option is to rename the imported name with `as`:

```
from ShutterDeck.Controller import User as ControllerUser
from ShutterDeck.Helper import User as HelperUser

u1 = ControllerUser.User()
u2 = HelperUser.User()
```

Answer (score 12):

One way is just:

```
import ShutterDeck.Controller.User
import ShutterDeck.Helper.User

cuser = ShutterDeck.Controller.User.User()
huser = ShutterDeck.Helper.User.User()
```

You can also do this:

```
from ShutterDeck.Controller.User import User as ControllerUser
from ShutterDeck.Helper.User import User as HelperUser
```

Answer (score 1):

This might also help (struggled with similar problem today):

```
ShutterDeck
├── Controller
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── User.py
├── Helper
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── User.py
└── __init__.py
```

in `ShutterDeck/{Controller,Helper}/__init__.py`:

```
from .User import User
```

And then:

```
>>> import ShutterDeck.Helper
>>> helperUser = ShutterDeck.Helper.User()
>>> helperUser
<ShutterDeck.Helper.User.User object at 0x1669b90>
>>> import ShutterDeck.Controller
>>> controllerUser = ShutterDeck.Controller.User()
>>> controllerUser
<ShutterDeck.Controller.User.User object at 0x1669c90>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can engineer `sys.modules` to do this.

If you have two files, version_file.py, which contain version information for two different modules/projects.

Import the first:

```
# NB use sys.path.insert(0, ...) to make this path the first path to be searched by the framework
sys.path.insert(0, str(project_a_dir_path)) # NB parent dir of version_file.py   
if 'version_file' in sys.modules:
    # ... deal with this: raise exception, delete key, log, etc. (see explanation below)
project_a_version_file_mod = importlib.import_module('version_file')
# make your own chosen key point to this newly imported module:
sys.modules['project_a_version_file_mod'] = sys.modules['version_file']
del sys.modules['version_file']
# preferably, delete from sys.path if this entry won't be used again:
del sys.path[0]
```

Then you process the other:

```
sys.path.insert(0, str(project_b_dir_path)) # NB parent dir of **its** version_file.py   
project_b_version_file_mod = importlib.import_module('version_file')
sys.modules['project_b_version_file_mod'] = sys.modules['version_file']
del sys.modules['version_file']
# preferably, delete entry from sys.path
del sys.path[0]
```

You now have two imported modules, `project_a_version_file_mod` and `project_b_version_file_mod`. Assuming both have an attr "version" you can get their respective values: `project_a_version_file_mod.version` and `project_b_version_file_mod.version`.

I'm not seeing anything problematic in this technique but would be interested to hear if anyone can point out any issues.

**Idiosyncracies and traps of the sys.modules dict**
NB it important to know, according to my experiments, that if `importlib.import_module` looks at `sys.modules` and finds a key there already for the next module it's being asked to add, it just ignores the new instruction! I find this quite strange, but that appears to be the case.

For this reason, if you don't delete (`del sys.modules['version_file']`) in the first import operation above, the second will fail (silently) to import on `import_module`, so in that case `project_b_version_file_mod` would in fact also be pointing at the version file module `project_a_version_file_mod`.

Similarly, if there is already an entry with key "version_file" before the first operation, the import operation wouldn't happen. That is why it is important to deal with that eventuality.

**Idiosyncracies and traps of the sys.path list**
NB2 Above, I recommend removing the entry added to `sys.path` enabling the module to be imported, after doing the import. The objection might then be raised "but supposing that added path was already present in sys.path?".

The answer to that is that `sys.path` is a `list`, not a `set`, so you can actually have multiple identical path entries, which is generally an undesirable thing, but which in this case makes this handling rather simple: by removing the added path you can guarantee you will return `sys.path` to the way it was before.