# Python Same Module Name Convention

Tags: python, naming, convention

In reference to this question:
[python: Two modules and classes with the same name under different packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720593/python-two-modules-and-classes-with-the-same-name-under-different-packages)

Should all modules in a package be uniquely named, regardless of nesting? PEP8 and PEP423 do not seem to address this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no requirement that names at different levels must be different. Each level is a separate namespace. If `foo.utils` and `foo.bar.utils` make sense in your project, just do so.

For example, the Python standard library has [`email.message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) and [`email.mime.message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html?highlight=email.mime.message#email.mime.message.MIMEMessage), and [`multiprocessing.connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection), as well as [`multiprocessing.dummy.connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy), and many more:

```
$ ls ~/Development/Library/cpython/Lib/**/*.py  | grep -v __ | grep -v test_ | xargs basename | sort | uniq -c | grep -v '  1 ' | sort
   2 abc.py
   2 ascii.py
   2 client.py
   2 connection.py
   2 constants.py
   2 dump.py
   2 errors.py
   2 filelist.py
   2 handlers.py
   2 log.py
   2 message.py
   2 parse.py
   2 parser.py
   2 process.py
   2 queues.py
   2 server.py
   2 spawn.py
   2 text.py
   2 tree.py
   3 main.py
   4 config.py
   5 support.py
   6 util.py
```

That's all modules that appear inside packages, appear more than once, excluding tests, `__init__.py` and `__main__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Since package is based on the filesystem, you can not, in normal circonstance, have the same packages because files/directories have no duplicate.

You can have the same namespace package, of course.

It is also possible to have the same package/module name in different paths. They are searched in order, so the first win.