# AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'binary' error invoking Headless Firefox using GeckoDriver through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-headless

```
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/Users/toprak/Desktop/geckodriver') 
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login?lang=en")
```

When I try to run my code, I get this error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Users/toprak/Desktop/topla.py", line 19
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/Users/toprak/Desktop/geckodriver')
DeprecationWarning: use options instead of firefox_options
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/toprak/Desktop/topla.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/Users/toprak/Desktop/geckodriver')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 137, in __init__
    if options.binary is not None:
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'binary'
```

When I delete the lines which are about options and take out "firefox_options=options", the code works fine. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to invoke firefox headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50414007/unable-to-invoke-firefox-headless)

Comment: Yes no luck sadly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `firefox_options` object you need to use `options` object. Additionally you need to use the `headless` attribute. So your effective code block will be:

```
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/toprak/Desktop/geckodriver', options=options) 
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login?lang=en")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to make Firefox headless programmatically in Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243)

Comment: Still gives the same "attributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'binary'" error

Comment: @Xia Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Answer (score 2):

The `--headless` argument works fine in Firefox (geckodriver) these days.

If you're getting the error mentioned in the title, then you're probably accidentally creating or passing a Chrome-based Options object rather than a Firefox-based Options object.

To avoid that mistake, it's best to create an import alias for both of them so that they're easier to distinguish.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"..\mypath\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)

firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')
firefox_driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r"..\mypath\geckodriver.exe", options=firefox_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

This 4 lines helped me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

...

    options = FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

If it still gives an error you can try to substitute fourth line to `driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)`

Reference - [Unable to invoke firefox headless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418446/8874665)