# Robot Framework Keyword Name Changing In Libraries

Tags: robotframework

I have been using the robot framework recently and with a requirement, I wanted use **seleniumLibrary** and the **SikuliLibrary** together. The problem was both selenium and sikuli libraries are using common keywords in some tasks like **"Input Text"**

To differentiate which library to use we need to add the library name in front of the keyword *( seleniumLibrary.Input Text, SikuliLibrary.Input Text )*

If not we can define custom keywords for those common keywords and use them.

Without going for any of the options is there a way to edit the keyword name in the library itself? So It will be easy and less complex for any who need to edit the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720593/python-two-modules-and-classes-with-the-same-name-under-different-packages), use the "as" when you import your functions to give them an other surname.

You can modify the function name in the library but I wont recomend that, it could cause regressions.

Regards,

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the info. If I can define a new library importing both selenium lib. and sikuli lib. keywords It should work it seems. Will try that out.

Comment: Hey, can you please add here that thing exactly. How you overcome the "Input Text" which is in both selenium and sikuli @MudithaPerera.